# Does $y=2/x$ have any lines of symmetry?

Tags: symmetry

Lines of symmetry for $y=1/x$ are $y=x$ and $y=-x$.

Does $y=2/x$ likewise have lines of symmetry?

Comment: the very same ones as y=1/x.

Comment: It's a hyperbola rotated $45^\circ$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All rectangular hyperbolae $ x \cdot y = k $ have lines of symmetry $ x=y,x= -y.$